# Low Disk Space on boot warning

Tags: boot

I am getting the following notice: "Low disk space on "boot".  The volume "boot" has only 0 bytes disk space remaining."

Is this a problem?  If so how do I resolve it?  Can I do it via GParted Partition Editor ..... the Editor is installed on my device and is in my System Tools 'folder'.  Per Gparted Editor my boot size is currently set at 243 MiB.

Answer (score 2):

Problem: Old, useless kernel copies that are generated when you upgrade them stuffed your tiny boot partition.

Solution: The package manager has gotten it from long years ago.

1. Open a terminal
2. Do `sudo apt-get autoremove`
3. If it says 'yes or no?' then say 'Y.'
4. Wait a sec and you're good.

Impact: You possibly become unable to reboot if the newest kernel is broken but if you're using sufficiently cool hard disk then enough, just do it.

Sorry for my bad English, though. It's very informal, also.

Comment: Kim thanks for your help.  Good news - I am able to reboot.    Bad news it only removed about 2.1mb of "junk".   So I have not really resolved the issue.  I believe that I will have to increase, significantly, the size of the boot partition.  So I have to do some research and learn how to increase boot size. Possibly from the usb thumb drive used to install Elementary on my Lenovo Tiny.